Conservative idempotent magma - proof attempt
I need help with checking proof about idempotent and conservative magmas.
Let magma be any ordered pair $(M, \odot)$, where $M$ is nonempty set and $\odot$ binary operation on $M$.
Now I need to introduce some special types of magmas:
$(M, \odot)$ is called idempotent $\iff \forall x \in M: (x \odot x) =x$
$(M, \odot)$ is called left-alternative $\iff\forall x,y \in M:  ((x\odot x)\odot y)=\\ (x \odot (x \odot y))$
$(M, \odot)$ is called right-alternative $\iff \forall x,y \in M: (y\odot(x \odot x))=\\ ((y\odot x)\odot x)$
$(M, \odot)$ is called alternative $\iff$ it is both left and right-alternative
$(M, \odot)$ is called conservative $\iff \forall x,y \in M: (x \odot y) \in \{x,y\}$
My hypothesis is: Let $(M, \odot)$ be any idempotent and conservative magma. Than $(M, \odot)$ is alternative.
I will show my attemt of proof of left-alternativity since right-alternativity uses similar steps.
Let $a,b$ are arbitrary elements of $M$. I want to show $((a\odot a)\odot b)= (a \odot (a \odot b))$. Because $(M, \odot)$ is idempotent, than $((a\odot a)\odot b)=(a\odot b)$. And by conservativity of $(M, \odot)$ I get $(a\odot b) \in \{a,b\}$. Now I want to examine both cases:
If $(a\odot b)=a$, than $(a \odot (a \odot b))=(a \odot a)=a$ by idempotency, so it is true that $((a\odot a)\odot b)= (a \odot (a \odot b))$.
If $(a\odot b)=b$, than $(a \odot (a \odot b))=(a \odot b)=b$, so it is true that $((a\odot a)\odot b)=(a \odot (a \odot b))$.
In both cases left-alternativity of $(M, \odot)$ holds, so $(M, \odot)$ should be left-alternative.
I want to add that I found that problem interesting because finite magma illustrating the game rock-scissors-paper $(H,\otimes)$ (where $H=\{r,s,p\}$ and for instance $(s \otimes r)=r$ because rock beat scissors or $(p \otimes p)=p$ because paper draw paper) is both idempotent and conservative magma (it is easy to see just from the "definition" of the game), so it should be alternative which is in my opinion not triviality to see.

Concerning the equations, it looks ok. Let me just add that if the magma is conservative, then it is idempotent, so you have redundancy there. Also, you ended up proving that $x(xy)=xy=(xy)y$, which seems a bit stronger than what you proposed to prove.
